# Using spaces in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to run a batch file to set permissions on a number of folders.

We have the following folder structure

Folder1 Folder1\Client1 Folder1\Client2 Folder1\Client3 Then within each client folder we have several sub folders e.g. Folder1\Client1\SubFolder1 Folder1\Client1\SubFolder2 Folder1\Client1\SubFolder3

I need to reset permissions on all the Subfolders in the example above and have the following code in a file called permissions.bat

```
for /f %%g in ('dir "f:\temp\" /ad /b') do for /f %%a in ('dir %%~fg /ad /b') do icacls 
"%%~fg\%%a" /grant:r domain\mygroup:(OI)(CI)M
```

This works fine but for Client and Subfolders that contain spaces it doesn't work.  For example

```
Folder1\Client1\Sub Folder 1
```

Would show up as

```
Folder1\Client1\Sub\
```

Closely followed by System cannot find the file specified error. Any ideas?

This is running on a 2003 Server by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir "f:\temp\" /ad /b') do (
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %%~fg /ad /b') do (
  icacls "%%~fg\%%a" /grant:r domain\mygroup:(OI)(CI)M
 )
)
```

`"delims="` disables delimiters and so applies the entire `dir` line to the metavariables (%%g, %%a) regardless of the spaces.

I've broken the command over many lines for ease of reading. You could put it all on one line if you prefer, when the <kbd>(</kbd> after each `do` and the final two <kbd>)</kbd> would become redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The default delimiters for a FOR loop are space and tab.  You need to specify delimiters to be only backslash.  For example:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%g in ('dir "f:\temp\" /ad /b') do ...
```

See here for more info:  [Tokens and Delims](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php)

There are a few other additional issues with the script, but I believe the following will work for you:

```
SET folder=F:\temp
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%g in ('dir "%folder%\" /ad /b') do for /f %%a in ('dir "%folder%\%%g" /ad /b') do icacls "%folder%\%%g\%%a" /grant:r domain\mygroup:(OI)(CI)M
```